# Big Query - different number of users when using legacy and normal sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have written a query in **Google Big Query** and want to get the same number of users I see in Google Analytics. I used Legacy and Normal SQL and got 3 different users numbers while the sessions were the same. What did I do wrong, or does anyone have an explanation/solution for it? Every help is appreciated!

**Normal SQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS users, SUM(IF(totals.visits IS 
NULL,0,totals.visits)) AS sessions
FROM `XXX.XXX.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181120' AND '20181120'
```

**Legacy SQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS users, SUM(IF(totals.visits IS 
NULL,0,totals.visits)) AS sessions
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXX:XXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2018-11-20'), 
TIMESTAMP('2018-11-20'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this warning from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) explains what is happening:

> In legacy SQL, COUNT(DISTINCT x) returns an approximate count. In standard SQL, it returns an exact count.

StandardSQL has the correct number.  You can test this by attempting to use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT()` in legacy SQL.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Now the numbers are the same, but there is still a difference between Google Analytics and Big Query. Any ideas?

Comment: @PierreWunderlich how much are you out and is this users, visits or both? Have you checked that Google Analytics is not sampling your data? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

Comment: The data is unsampled and the difference is small, but there is one. Sessions are the same in GA and Big Query.